# Using Enter key to invoke different methods in Mac(objective c)

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I am new to Objective c programming. I have created an application which has a UI with two buttons "Cancel" and "Ok". On clicking "Cancel", the application must terminate and clicking "Ok" must perform some task. Everything works fine. I am able to tab between these buttons and can call the required functionality by clicking space button.
All I want to do is, that when focus is on "Cancel" button(using tab key) then on clicking enter button from keyboard, my application should terminate and similarly, when focus is on "Ok" button then clicking enter should perform the desired functionality.

I have even set the 'setKeyEquivalent" property of the "Ok" and "Cancel" button, but I can only set unique keyequivalents. I also tried to read the title or tag value of the buttons and then call the required functionality but it didn't worked too.

Can someone please guide me how can I use enter button to invoke different functions depending upon the selected button in UI.

Comment: First, just so you know, not all users will have configured their accounts to allow tabbing to buttons. Second, for those who have, they expect the Space key to activate the focused control. They expect the Return key to activate the default control, even if another is focused. Note that Return and Enter are two different keys; the latter is on the numeric keypad on full-size keyboards. (I think it's fn-Return on compact keyboards.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't want to set key equivalents for the buttons.  You would want to override keyDown: and test for the enter key, then do the appropriate thing depending on which button had focus (which I think you could determine using NSWindow's firstResponder method).